# Symfony 2.8 form entity type custom property

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I'm working on a form in a Symfony 2.8 application.

I have an entity Object and that entity can have one or more SubObjects.
Those SubObjects are identified by the property **id**, but also by the property **key**.

By default the value from the **id** property is used in the HTML (subObject.__toString()). I want to use the property **key** in the .

I can't seem to find how to do this...

PS: I can't use the __toString() method of the SubObject, because that's already in use for some other purposes...

Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

namespace My\Bundle\ObjectBundle\Form\Type\Object;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ObjectType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('code', TextType::class, [
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('subObjects', EntityType::class, [
                'class'    => 'My\Bundle\ObjectBundle\Entity\SubObject',
                'multiple' => true,
            ])
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with the key, can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Richard I'm not showing the "id" of the SubObject anywhere. Only the "key" is a "known property" to the outside world. What I'd like to do is to do this: form[subObjects][0]=7TBF65Dtufbg7ung&form[subObjects][1]=IBIU76ghh and use those "keys" to load the SubObject from the DB and "connect" them to the Object.

I hope I've explained it properly..

Comment: I see. It would probably be best to write a form listener that populates the subObjects collection based on your logic criteria.

Comment: I have been thinking about that, but it feels a bit like a "hack"... I'd be astonished if this is not configurable trough the array options of EntityTpe...

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding correctly, you have a generic object, that loads another object (of some type) based on a key? That seems unlikely you can do it in EntityType.

Comment: @Richard I have an Object that has many SubObjects. Join column is id. I never show the column id in the frontend so I'd like to use the column key in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chucked up a quick pseudocode of how I'd do this in a listener, hopefully I understood what you're after. It's a general approach anyway.

```
class ResolveSubObjectSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    /** @var  EntityManager */
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory, EntityManager $entityManager) {

        $this->factory = $factory;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA => 'resolveSubObject');
    }

    /**
     *  Resolve sub objects based on key
     *
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function resolveSubObject(FormEvent $event) {

        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // don't care if it's not a sub object
        if (!$data instanceof SubObject) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var SubObject $subObject */
        $subObject = $data;

        // here you do whatever you need to do to populate the object into the sub object based on key

        $subObjectByKey = $this->entityManager->getRepository('SomeRepository')->findMySubObject($subObject->getKey());
        $subObject->setObject($subObjectByKey);
   }
}
```

Comment: An event listener is an option indeed, but I think this should be possible without custom listeners / transformers.